# How to SharePoint Online List Items with Kendo UI Grid using ODATA and Transport URL

Tags: jquery, odata, sharepoint-online, kendo-ui-grid

Kendo UI Grid Support OData. SharePoint Online also have OData V3 supports. 
I am able to configured it properly to read data as per below code.

But I have list with more than 5k records and SP Online have threshold limit of 5k.

So I want to configured server paging/filter/sorting and I tried below approach.

Here it render first 500 items properly but next button click is not working with dynamic url. On requestEnd it provides next query to execute but how to attach that with pager change event to work.

any help will be appreciated!

I tried to fire multiple API using Javascript/angularjs and prepare local variable with all items first and then assigned to grid. its working but performance is very poor. so expecting dynamic approach.

```
var kdatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: {
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitleWithMoreThan5K')/items" //$scope.NextQuery,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose")
                }
            }
        },
        sort: { field: "ID" , dir: "desc"}, 
        requestEnd: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            var response = e.response;
            var type = e.type;
            console.log(type); // displays "read"
            if(response)
            {
                //console.log(e.response.d.__next);
                $scope.NextQuery = e.response.d.__next; //getting next query in response. SP Online have 'SkipToken' not 'skip' for listitems. 
                console.log($scope.NextQuery);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (data) {
                return data.d && data.d.results ? data.d.results : [data.d];
            },
            total: function (data) {
                return 3000;//we can take care this with separate itemcount query
            },
            model: {
                fields: {
                    "ID": { type: "number" },
                    "Title": { type: "string" }
                }
            },
            errors: function (response) {
                console.error(response);
                return response.error;
            }
        },
        page:1,
        pageSize: 500, // this will become "$top" in query
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: kdatasource,
    columns: [{
                    field: "ID",
                    title: "ID",
                    width: 240
                },{
                    field: "Title",
                    title: "Title",
                    width: 240
                }],
    height: 550,
    groupable: false,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: false,
        //pageSize: 10,
        pageSizes: [100, 200, 500, 1000],                   
        buttonCount: 5,
        change:function(e)
        {
             console.log("grid pager clicked!");
             console.log(e);
             //how to rebind grid for 2, 3, page number click?
        }
    } ,
    dataBound: function(e) {
        //console.log(e); // This is calling!
        //console.log("dataBound");
    }
});
```

Paging/Filter/Sorting must work with SharePoint using REST API queries

Answer (score 0):

From your code I see that you are reading **all items** from 5k list using SharePoint REST api I would advise to get items with CAML that will have some filters.

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitleWithMoreThan5K')/items"
```

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208020/make-caml-query-with-in-rest-api-call

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late but I have used parameter map to make proper query.

@Rafal, The issue was Kendo Ui Grid is creating server query dynamically based on configurations for ODATA but SharePoint dont follow exactly same parameters which is followed in ODATA.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.parametermap

Hope, this will help to someone like me.